# How to create API client from wsdl file?

Tags: java, web-services, api, wsdl

I have wsdl 
http://www.webservicex.net/genericbarcode.asmx?WSDL .
I am trying to create a client, looking for logic in wsdl.

I think it should start from this:

```
BarCode barCode=new BarCode();
    BarCodeSoap barCodeSoap=barCode.getBarCodeSoap();
```

Do I need to input any parameters there?

Answer (score 1):

Executable code is generated from WSDL of the Webservice. The client then uses  this code to access the Webservice.

For example, [**GlassFish**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) includes `vsimport` utility to generate Java code from WSDL.

This utility generates a lot of compiled Java classes that allows client applications to  access to Webservices. These classes are further to be added to `classpath` of the client.

In addition, GlassFish includes custom Ant task (also there are Maven plugin for that).

Then you need to use `@WebServiceRef` annotation that inject the instance of the Webservice to you client.

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="...?wsdl")
private static NameOfYouServiceService nameOfYouServiceService;
...
```

`NameOfYouService` - this is convention, the name of Webservice that you develop.

Then this call `nameOfYouServiceService.getNameOfYouServicePort()` return you instance of the Webservice. Then you can free use methods of the instance.

Here, the name `NameOfYouService` - also convention.

In short, something like that.

---

Your Webservice is written in .NET technology, but you can also using Java client (or PHP or something else) to access it. In fact, a web service created with one technology can be accessed by clients in any other technology.

Here is a good article for your case: [Java Client for WebServiceX.Net Web Service (NetBeans IDE)](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/webservicexclient.aspx)

Comment: thx for answer, Ialready did wsimport and have all classes in my IDE, question was specificly about how to use this classes, is it clear how to use them from wsdl file? There is some logic which methods trigger another ones, can't figure out how to use them)